# What is the momentum of these emitted photons?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, momentum, radioactivity

`5 x 10^7 kg of radioactive material emits energy in the form of photons of red light (700 nm). (Note: photons have no mass.)
What is the momentum of each photon?`

We just started a new chapter, and in the process of learning it, I came across this question in the back of our book, which I am really having trouble understanding right now. Can anyone suggest how I can go about solving this (note, I would like to actually work out the problem myself; however, I need a sufficiant place to start.) Obviously, the Newtonian equations like `p =m/v` will not apply here, so I'm somewhat stuck at the moment...

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The momentum of a photon is inversely proportional to its wavelength $\lambda$:

$p=\frac{h}{\lambda},$

where $h$ is the Planck constant.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is as usual https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon .